# Nested scrollviews getting problematic

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview

My problem is that I am using nested scrollviews. One for the horizontal paging and second to show the content with vertical scrolling (cuz content, which is text, is more than the available space). Actually there are multiple copies of this vertical scrollview like:

```
MainScrollView (Horizontal)
     VerticalScrollView1
     VerticalScrollView2
     VerticalScrollView3
```

Besides these the vertical scrollviews contains label that are draggable, I implemented dragging using touchesBegan: and moved: events. I developed the whole thing using only one vertical scrollview and it's working just fine and I thought, to my dismay, that it'll work exactly the same for the rest but when I added more vertical scrollviews, only the last one is allowing dragging of the labels. The first two ain't allowing dragging, besides, they are also not responding to the vertical scrolling event, which was perfect earlier. I tried it with two vertical scrollviews and even then only the last one was allowing dragging. Ain't sure about the vertical scrolling cuz right now only the first one has enough content to be scrolled rest need not to. I can try that out too but it's kinda late here, so, if someone can guide me with the provided info. would be much helpful. Else I can try that out tomorrow and post you with the result.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues with nesting UIScrollviews. I found this video from WWDC 2010 to be really helpful in showing how to work with scrollviews inside a paging scrollview, and I managed to fix the bugs I had by following the steps in this video and looking at the sample code.

[Designing Apps with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) 
[Sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html)